# How to run a Qt executable file dependent on .dll files?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, exe

So I've finished my Qt application, and I need to implement testing using the Squish testing application (first time using).  Apparently I require a working exe file, but I can't get the executable to run.  I added all the .dll files to the same directory, only to get  the error:  [image]

Prior to that I was getting errors saying that `XXXX.dll is missing`, but like I said, I've added them to the directory. I've tried using both debug and release builds of my project with the same results.  I've also tried building a stand-alone executable, but that has it's own problems (one thing at a time).  The program runs great in Qt Creator and VS2013...just not on its own.

Any solutions to this?

**EDIT:**
From Dependency Walker...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x7B is the error code for invalid image format.

You're either trying to run a 64-bit application on a 32-bit system, or linking to a 64-bit library (ie you copied the wrong DLLs).

Or your binaries are just corrupted.

Comment: I'm running on a 64bit system.  I've also tried rebuilding my project and running on a different 64bit computer with a fresh install of Qt from a separate download.  The problem persists.

Comment: Run the executable with dependency walker to see which DLL is in the wrong format.

Comment: Okay, first time using Dependency Walker, but if I'm reading it correctly it says that ICUIN53.DLL is x86 in the CPU field.  It also has about 8 other modules that error when opening.  Educated shot in the dark...this is the problem?  I've posted a picture in the update above.

Comment: @LazyBear That's what I was expecting to see. Your 64bit executable is loading a 32bit `ICUIN52.DLL`. The other errors where it says it can't find `WINRT....dll` etc. are normally there and aren't worth worrying about.

Comment: @sjdowling  ICUIN53.DLL is one of the DLLs it explicitly said it needed, and I added.  But it's in the same bin folder with all the x64 DLL files.  If I can't get a x64 version in a 64bit installation of Qt, where can I get it?

Comment: @LazyBear That doesn't seem right. The 64bit Qt installations I have all have 64bit ICU dlls. Are you sure they haven't been overwritten somehow?

Comment: Or you're reading them from the wrong place. I don't actually have or use Qt, but it seems clear that this is the issue.

Comment: @sjdowling I don't see how, unless the most recent version added the wrong DLL.  I have the same problem on a separate computer with a fresh install of Qt from a separate download.  Same version though...top of the list.

Comment: @Bindy I did a straight copy and past from the Qt file itself.  It's cropped out in the pic, but the path is the one in the exe's directory.  So it's not reading a different DLL.

Comment: "From the Qt file itself" is what I mean. Qt is a huge library, with both 32 and 64 bit builds. Chances are you copied your file from the 32 bit portion -- further evidenced by the fact that if you don't do this copying, it works right? So the right DLL is obviously on your system. You just didn't get it.

Comment: @Bindy I though I might be pulling from a separate build when  saw the DW data, but his is where I got it. `C:\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2013_64\bin`  I don't even see a 32bit build folder.   I'm going to do another fresh install from download from a different mirror.  Maybe that'll have the correct file. Worth a shot anyway.

Comment: If your executable works without copying this file on your dev machine, simply delete it from your binary folder and use Dependency Walker to see where the DLL it uses is (probably in System32). Then take that!

Comment: @Blindy So I just reinstalled Qt...again.  Then, I ran through the steps you guys helped me with above, using a release build.  Presto!  It works.  Thanks for the insight and help.

Comment: @sjdowling So I just reinstalled Qt...again. Then, I ran through the steps you guys helped me with above, using a release build. Presto! It works. Thanks for the insight and help.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the application standalone (i.e. not from Qt Creator) you also need the Qt library DLLs. which one you need, depends on the components you are using.

[Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com)  is also a useful tool to find missing DLLs under Windows.

Comment: One of the things I tried was I kinda going nuclear by adding every Qt library DLL in the bin folder. Same problem. But I'll try Dependency Walker to see if there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

As for me it seems that something is missing. Qt on windows has the script windeployqt, it will provide all needed dependencies. See documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html about use of this. On Windows you will be able to run cmd with loaded qt environment variables ( on Windows 7 see under windows applications menu - it will be available if qt is installed ). As Simon stated Dependency Walker is good tool.